Is it possible to get a dict of fields with FieldInfo from the Pydantic Dataclass?
When creating classes by inheriting from BaseModel, I can use the model_fields property to get a dict of field names, and FieldInfo, but how can I do it if I use the Pydantic Dataclass decorator instead of BaseModel?
When using BaseModel I can do this:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Person(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(alias='firstName')
    age: int

p = Person(firstName='John', age=42)

p.model_fields

p.model_fields will return dict[str, FieldInfo] with all the information about fields:
{'first_name': FieldInfo(annotation=str, required=True, alias='firstName', alias_priority=2),

'age': FieldInfo(annotation=int, required=True)}
I want get same info about fields when using Pydantic's dataclasses:
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import Field

@dataclass
class Person:
    first_name: str = Field(alias='firstName')
    age: int

p = Person(firstName='John', age=42)
# p.model_fields doesn't exists

I looked at RootModel and there's nothing, I tried TypeAdapter which has core_schema but it has different structure and no FieldInfo objects.
Is there no way to get this infro from Pydantic's dataclass?

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for (at least the format is a little bit different), but I found the following way:
import dataclasses

from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Item:
    value: int = Field(..., description="Description")


item = Item(value=1)
dataclasses.fields(item)


Hi, thanks for the reply. dataclasses.fields(item) returns list of Fields objects which are not same as Pydantic's FieldInfo objects which provide more information.
